# What exactly is meant by variational distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, variational-autoencoder, diffusion-models

What specifically does the term "variational distribution" refer to?

- The encoder of Variational autoencoder?
- Forward process of denoising diffusion probabilistic models?
- Images or latent variables?
  [image]

Answer (score 3):

The variational distribution is the **distribution (or set of distributions) that you use to approximate the distribution you are looking for**. It's often denoted by $q$, $q_\phi$ or $q_\phi(z \mid x)$, where $\phi$ are the variational parameters. For example, in the case of a Gaussian distribution, $\phi = \{ \mu, \sigma \}$. In the case of the VAE, $q_\phi(z \mid x)$ approximates $p(z \mid x)$ and the encoder outputs $\phi$, which can be used to sample $z$, a latent vector, which encodes the original input $x$ (e.g. an image).

So, the variational distribution is not the latent space or vector. However, you can speak of variational parameters, which would be $\phi$, and the latent vector is sampled from the variational distribution.

The VAEs use a general approach to learn distributions, which is called **variational inference**. I think the term **variational** comes from **calculus of variations**, which studies how to optimize functionals, like the ELBO, which is optimized in the VAE. You can read about it in [this blog post](https://mbernste.github.io/posts/variational_inference/) (I didn't really read it but it looks ok).

[This](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/main/vae/main.py) is the simplest implementation of the VAE that I know of, which I recommend you check out.

Right now, I don't know anything about diffusion models, so I don't know if they adopt these techniques.

(I did my master's thesis, a few years ago, on the application of Bayesian neural networks, some of which are based on variational inference, to a specific context)

Comment: Thank you very much. I get it in the case of VAE.

Comment: @diffusionstable If the diffusion models use variational inference, then the concept of the variational distribution that I describe here should also apply to them. But maybe someone will provide an answer that addresses that specific case.